# Create Multiple Sheet in jExcel API

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I need to create multiple excel sheet in Java using `jExcel API` if one sheet is full `(65536 rows)`. Suppose if one sheet got full then in the next sheet it should start writing automatically from where it left off in the first sheet. I am just stuck on putting the logic to create it dynamically whenever one sheet is full. Below is the code that I have done so far.

```
public void write() throws IOException, WriteException {
    File file = new File(inputFile);
    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

    wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);

    writingToExcel(workbook);
}


//Logic to create sheet dyanmically if one is full should be done here I guess?
private void writingToExcel(WritableWorkbook workbook) {

    workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
    WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    try {
        createLabel(excelSheet);
        createContent(excelSheet);
    } catch (WriteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

private void createLabel(WritableSheet sheet) throws WriteException {

    WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10);
    times = new WritableCellFormat(times10pt);
    times.setWrap(true);

    WritableFont times10ptBoldUnderline = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10, WritableFont.BOLD, false,UnderlineStyle.SINGLE);
    timesBoldUnderline = new WritableCellFormat(times10ptBoldUnderline);
    timesBoldUnderline.setWrap(true);

    CellView cv = new CellView();
    cv.setFormat(times);
    cv.setFormat(timesBoldUnderline);
    cv.setAutosize(true);

    // Write a few headers
    addCaption(sheet, 0, 0, "Header 1");
    addCaption(sheet, 1, 0, "This is another header");

}

private void createContent(WritableSheet sheet) throws WriteException,
        RowsExceededException {

    for (int i = 1; i < 70000; i++) {
        addNumber(sheet, 0, i, i + 10);
        addNumber(sheet, 1, i, i * i);
    }
}

private void addCaption(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
        throws RowsExceededException, WriteException {
    Label label;
    label = new Label(column, row, s, timesBoldUnderline);
    sheet.addCell(label);
}

private void addNumber(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row,
        Integer integer) throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
    Number number;
    number = new Number(column, row, integer, times);
    sheet.addCell(number);
}
```

I am not sure how to add that logic here in my code.

Any suggestions will be of great help?

Or in any case, can anyone provide me a simple example in which if one sheet is full, it should start writing automatically into different sheet (Second sheet)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made changes to the following 2 methods:-

```
private void writingToExcel(WritableWorkbook workbook) {
    try {
        // don't create a sheet now, instead, pass it in the workbook
        createContent(workbook);
    }
    catch (WriteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (WriteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

// instead of taking a sheet, take a workbook because we cannot ensure if the sheet can fit all the content at this point
private void createContent(WritableWorkbook workbook) throws WriteException {

    int excelSheetIndex = 0;
    int rowIndex = 0;
    WritableSheet excelSheet = null;

    for (int i = 1; i < 70000; i++) {

        // if the sheet has hit the cap, then create a new sheet, new label row and reset the row count
        if (excelSheet == null || excelSheet.getRows() == 65536) {
            excelSheet = workbook.createSheet("Report " + excelSheetIndex, excelSheetIndex++);
            createLabel(excelSheet);
            rowIndex = 0;
        }

        // instead of using i for row, use rowIndex
        addNumber(excelSheet, 0, rowIndex, i + 10);
        addNumber(excelSheet, 1, rowIndex, i * i);

        // increment the sheet row
        rowIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class DscMigration {

```
private WritableCellFormat timesBoldUnderline;
private WritableCellFormat times;
private String inputFile;

public void setOutputFile(String inputFile) {
    this.inputFile = inputFile;
}

public void write() throws IOException, WriteException {
    File file = new File(inputFile);
    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

    wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
    workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
    WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    createLabel(excelSheet);
    createContent(excelSheet);

    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
}

private void createLabel(WritableSheet sheet) throws WriteException {
    // Lets create a times font
    WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10);
    // Define the cell format
    times = new WritableCellFormat(times10pt);
    // Lets automatically wrap the cells
    times.setWrap(true);

    // Create create a bold font with unterlines
    WritableFont times10ptBoldUnderline = new WritableFont(
            WritableFont.TIMES, 10, WritableFont.BOLD, false,
            UnderlineStyle.SINGLE);
    timesBoldUnderline = new WritableCellFormat(times10ptBoldUnderline);
    // Lets automatically wrap the cells
    timesBoldUnderline.setWrap(true);

    CellView cv = new CellView();
    cv.setFormat(times);
    // cv.setFormat(timesBoldUnderline);
    // cv.setFormat(cf)
    cv.setAutosize(true);

    // Write a few headers
    addCaption(sheet, 0, 0, "COM_ID");
    addCaption(sheet, 1, 0, "OBJECTID");
    addCaption(sheet, 2, 0, "GNOSISID");

}

private void createContent(WritableSheet sheet) throws WriteException,
        RowsExceededException {

    /**
     * Create a new instance for cellDataList
     */
    List<DataObj> cellDataListA = new ArrayList<DataObj>();
    List<DataObj> nonDuplicateA = new ArrayList<DataObj>();
    List<DataObj2> cellDataListB = new ArrayList<DataObj2>();
    List<DataObj2> nonDuplicateB = new ArrayList<DataObj2>();
    List<DataObj> nonDuplicateAB = new ArrayList<DataObj>();
    List<DataObj> misMatchAB = new ArrayList<DataObj>();
    List<DataObj> copyA = new ArrayList<DataObj>();
    List<DataObj2> comID = new ArrayList<DataObj2>();

    try {
        /**
         * Create a new instance for FileInputStream class
         */
        // input1--> col1 -livelink id ; col2->livlink filename; col3-> gnosis id; col4-> filename
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                "C:/Documents and Settings/nithya/Desktop/DSC/Report/input1.xls");
    //input2 --> col1 comid all, col2 -> object id for common
        FileInputStream fileInputStream2 = new FileInputStream(
        "C:/Documents and Settings/nithya/Desktop/DSC/Report/input2.xls");

        /**
         * Create a new instance for POIFSFileSystem class
         */
        POIFSFileSystem fsFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(fileInputStream);
        POIFSFileSystem fsFileSystem2 = new POIFSFileSystem(fileInputStream2);
        /*
         * Create a new instance for HSSFWorkBook Class
         */
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsFileSystem);
        HSSFSheet hssfSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFWorkbook workBook2 = new HSSFWorkbook(fsFileSystem2);
        HSSFSheet hssfSheet2 = workBook2.getSheetAt(0);
        /**
         * Iterate the rows and cells of the spreadsheet to get all the
         * datas.
         */
        Iterator rowIterator = hssfSheet.rowIterator();
        Iterator rowIterator2 = hssfSheet2.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow hssfRow = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();

            if ((hssfRow.getCell((short) 0) != null)
                    && (hssfRow.getCell((short) 1) != null)) {
                cellDataListA.add(new DataObj(hssfRow.getCell((short) 0)
                        .toString().trim(), hssfRow.getCell((short) 1)
                        .toString().trim()));
            }

            if ((hssfRow.getCell((short) 2) != null)
                    && (hssfRow.getCell((short) 3) != null)) {
                cellDataListB.add(new DataObj2(hssfRow.getCell((short) 2)
                        .toString().trim(), hssfRow.getCell((short) 3)
                        .toString().trim()));
            }

        }
        // Replace Duplicate in Livelink Startd
        Set set = new HashSet();
        List newList = new ArrayList();
        nonDuplicateA.addAll(cellDataListA);
        for (int i = 0; i < nonDuplicateA.size(); i++) {
            DataObj b = nonDuplicateA.get(i);
            if (set.add(b.getCol1()))
                newList.add(nonDuplicateA.get(i));
        }

        nonDuplicateA.clear();
        nonDuplicateA.addAll(newList);
        for (int i = 0; i < nonDuplicateA.size(); i++) {
            DataObj a = nonDuplicateA.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println("nonDuplicateA=="+nonDuplicateA.size());
        // Replace Duplicate in Livelink End

        // Replace Duplicate in Gnosis Startd
        Set set2 = new HashSet();
        List newList2 = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("cellDataListB=="+cellDataListB.size());
        nonDuplicateB.addAll(cellDataListB);
        for (int i = 0; i < nonDuplicateB.size(); i++) {
            DataObj2 b = nonDuplicateB.get(i);
                if (set2.add(b.getCol1()))
                newList2.add(nonDuplicateB.get(i));
        }

        nonDuplicateB.clear();
        nonDuplicateB.addAll(newList2);

        System.out.println("nonDuplicateB=="+nonDuplicateB.size());
        // Replace Duplicate in Gnosis End

        // Common record
        //System.out.println("------Common----");
        for (int i = 0; i < nonDuplicateA.size(); i++) {
            DataObj a = nonDuplicateA.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < nonDuplicateB.size(); j++) {
                DataObj2 b = nonDuplicateB.get(j);

                    if((a.getCol2()!=null && b.getCol2()!=null )){
                        //System.out.println("---------");
                if (a.getCol2().equalsIgnoreCase(b.getCol2())) {

                //  System.out.println(a.getCol2() +"--"+i+"--"+b.getCol2());
                    nonDuplicateAB.add(new DataObj(a.getCol1().toString()
                            .trim(), b.getCol1().toString().trim()));
                    //addLabel(sheet, 0, i, a.getCol1().toString().trim());
                    // addLabel(sheet, 1, i, b.getCol1().toString().trim());
                    break;
                }


            }

            }

        }
        System.out.println("nonDuplicateAB=="+nonDuplicateAB.size());
        TreeMap misA = new TreeMap();
        //System.out.println("------Missing----");
        for (int i = 0; i < nonDuplicateA.size(); i++) {
            DataObj a = nonDuplicateA.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < nonDuplicateB.size(); j++) {
                DataObj2 b = nonDuplicateB.get(j);
                    if((a.getCol2()!=null && b.getCol2()!=null )){
                    if (!(a.getCol2().equals(b.getCol2()))) {
                    //System.out.println(a.getCol1() +"="+b.getCol1());

                    //break;

                    if(misA.containsValue(a.getCol2())){
                        misA.remove(a.getCol1());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        misA.put(a.getCol1(), a.getCol2());
                    }
                }

            }

            }
        }
        //System.out.println("SIze mis="+misA);
        TreeMap misB = new TreeMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < nonDuplicateB.size(); i++) {
            DataObj2 a = nonDuplicateB.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < nonDuplicateA.size(); j++) {
                DataObj b = nonDuplicateA.get(j);
                    if((a.getCol2()!=null && b.getCol2()!=null )){
                    if (!(a.getCol2().equals(b.getCol2()))) {
                    //System.out.println(a.getCol1() +"="+b.getCol1());


                    if(misB.containsValue(a.getCol2())){
                        misB.remove(a.getCol1());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        misB.put(a.getCol1(), a.getCol2());
                    }
                }

            }

            }
        }
    //  System.out.println("SIze misB="+misB);
        //Getting ComID and Object Id from excel start
        while (rowIterator2.hasNext()) {

            HSSFRow hssfRow2 = (HSSFRow) rowIterator2.next();

            if ((hssfRow2.getCell((short) 0) != null)
                    && (hssfRow2.getCell((short) 1) != null)) {
                comID.add(new DataObj2(hssfRow2.getCell((short) 0)
                        .toString().trim(), hssfRow2.getCell((short) 1)
                        .toString().trim()));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Size ComID="+comID.size());
        TreeMap hm = new TreeMap(); 
        System.out.println("Please wait...Data comparison.. ");
        for (int i = 0; i < nonDuplicateAB.size(); i++) {
            DataObj a = nonDuplicateAB.get(i);
            for(int j=0;j<comID.size();j++ ){
                DataObj2 b = comID.get(j);
                //System.out.println((b.getCol2()+"---"+a.getCol1()));

                if(b.getCol2().equalsIgnoreCase(a.getCol1())){
                    hm.put(b.getCol1(), b.getCol2());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Size HM="+hm.size());
        //Getting ComID and Object Id from excel End

        //Data Base Updation
        Connection conn = null;
        try {

            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
                       conn =   DriverManager.getConnection(
                      "jdbc:oracle:thin:@cxxxxx:5487:dev", "",
                      "");

        System.out.println("after calling conn");

                Set set6 = hm.entrySet(); 
                Iterator i = set6.iterator(); 
                String gnosisNodeId="";
                int update=1;
                while(i.hasNext()) { 
                Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
                //System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": "); 
                //System.out.println(me.getValue()); 
        //  System.out.println("nonDuplicateAB="+nonDuplicateAB.size());
                for(int m=0;m<nonDuplicateAB.size();m++){
                    DataObj a = nonDuplicateAB.get(m);
                    if(me.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(a.getCol1())){
                    gnosisNodeId=a.getCol2().toString();
                    nonDuplicateAB.remove(m);
                    break;
                    }
                }
                //System.out.println("nonDuplicateAB="+nonDuplicateAB.size());
                if(gnosisNodeId!=null){
                    //System.out.println("LOOP");
                String s1="UPDATE component SET com_xml =  UPDATEXML(com_xml, '*/url/value/text()', '";
                String s2="http://dmfwebtop65.pfizer.com/webtop/drl/objectId/"+gnosisNodeId;
                String s3="') where com_id="+me.getKey().toString().substring(1)+"";
                Statement   stmt1=null;
                //http://dmfwebtop65.pfizer.com/webtop/drl/objectId/0901201b8239cefb
                    try {
                        String updateString1 = s1+s2+s3; 
                        stmt1 = conn.createStatement();

                        int rows =stmt1.executeUpdate(updateString1);
                 if (rows>0) {
                     addLabel(sheet, 0, update, me.getKey().toString().substring(1));
                        addLabel(sheet, 1, update, me.getValue().toString().substring(1));
                        addLabel(sheet, 2, update,gnosisNodeId );
                        update++;   
                    System.out.println("Update Success="+me.getKey().toString().substring(1)+ "-->" +me.getValue().toString().substring(1));
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 System.out.println("Not Updated="+me.getKey().toString().substring(1)+ "-->" +me.getValue().toString().substring(1));
                 }

                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        System.out.println("No Connect" + e);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
                        } 
                }
                else{System.out.println("No gnosis id found for ObjectID="+me.getKey().toString().substring(1)); }

            }//While 
        } //try
     catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}//Main try
     catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
} //method

private void addCaption(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
        throws RowsExceededException, WriteException {
    Label label;
    label = new Label(column, row, s, timesBoldUnderline);
    sheet.addCell(label);
}

private void addNumber(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row,
        Integer integer) throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
    Number number;
    number = new Number(column, row, integer, times);
    sheet.addCell(number);
}

private void addLabel(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
        throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
    Label label;
    label = new Label(column, row, s, times);
    sheet.addCell(label);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws WriteException, IOException {
    DscMigration test = new DscMigration();
    test.setOutputFile("C:/Documents and Settings/nithya/Desktop/DSC/Report/Mapping.xls");
    test.write();
    System.out
            .println("Please check the result file under C:/Documents and Settings/nithya/Desktop/DSC/Report/Report.xls ");
}
```

}
XXXXInternal Use
Based on WTTE-0043 ELC Maintenance Release and Bug Fix Plan Template 
Version 4.0 Effective Date: 01-Jul-2010
//Bug Fix Plan

Author:
1 Approval Signatures

Table of Contents
I have authored this deliverable to document the plan for executing a maintenance release or bug fix to project.
NAME DATE
I have authored this deliverable to document the plan for executing a maintenance release or bug fix to XXX Plus v4.5.
NAME DATE

I approve this change and agree that this record represents the accurate and complete plan for executing the maintenance release or bug fix, and fully supports the implementation, testing and release activities for this project.
NAME DATE
I have reviewed the content of this record and found that it meets the applicable BT compliance requirements.
NAME DATE

Signatures
2 Introduction
This project deliverable documents the requested change, planned approach, development solution, test plan, test results and release approval for a maintenance release or and bug fix to project.

3 Change Request 
Requestor Name:

XX
Object/
System Name:

project
Priority (High/Medium/Low):

High
Change Request No.:
NA
Change Request Date:

22-NOV-2011

Description of Problem or Requested Change:

Estimated Development Time Needed:

1 day (approx.)

4)4 Maintenance Release and Bug Fix Approach
5 Development Solution
8 Supporting References
9 Revision History